# KQL - Joining 2 tables sing Equality by Value

Tags: kql, askql, kqlmagic

I am attempting to join two tables in KQL within Microsoft Defender.

These tables don't have matching columns however they do have matching fields.

LeftTable: `EmailEvents` Field: `RecipientEmailAddress`

RightTable: `IdentityInfo` Field: `AccountUpn`

The query I am using is as follows

```
EmailEvents
| where EmailDirection == "Inbound"
| where Subject == "invoice" or SenderFromAddress == "testtest@outlook.com"
| project RecipientEmailAddress, Subject, InternetMessageId, SenderFromAddress
| join kind=inner (IdentityInfo 
| distinct AccountUpn, AccountDisplayName, JobTitle , Department, City, Country) 
on $left.RecipientEmailAddress -- $right.AccountUpn
```

I am seeing the error

Semantic error
Error message
join: only column entities or equality expressions are allowed in this context.
How to resolve
Fix semantic errors in your query

Can someone assist I am not sure where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Please format the question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this:

`on $left.RecipientEmailAddress -- $right.AccountUpn`

with this:

`on $left.RecipientEmailAddress == $right.AccountUpn`